# Balancing an object with two loads

Tags: angular-momentum, rotational-dynamics, moment-of-inertia

Suppose a bar (black) sitting on a suspended ball (blue) has two rigid loads of equal weight attached to it (red):

[image]

Will the ball balance on the blue ball given even when the connection points of the two loads are different? Much of the mass are in the bulge portion, but with them both below the edges of the black bar, are the moments of inertia equal despite that the connection points are positioned differently?

Comment: There is no "green" weight in the picture.

Comment: How are the weighted loads attached? are the rigid loads connected by rigid rods, connected to the black bar by a sliding cam? Or is this rigidly attached? I recommend summing the moments, if they are equal then the weights will be in balance. To do this rigorously, you need to know the shapes of each component and how they are connected to the black bar. Also, your description says the rigid loads are red and green, but both are red.

Comment: @kennytm Sorry, fixed typo. Both weights are meant to be red.

Comment: @Charlie Sorry, the two weights are meant to be red. Yes, they're connected by rigid rods - one is at an angle.

Comment: The rod may be rigid, but is the connection rigid also? Or can the rigid rod rotate about its connection to the black block? This is important too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

An easy way to think about this, is that the mass moves as a whole. So when balancing, it doesn't "know" whether the triangular space above the left weight is filled or not. The attachment point doesn't matter. It could even be attached to the right of the support. What matters in mechanical terms is the total moment around the support (it'll rotate until this reaches zero, in this case, and won't fall off), or in energy terms until the potential energy is minimised.